# I have written a query and it is giving right dataset but don't know why it is not getting accepted?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, dml

The link of the question is
in http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref.

The schema is

- Product(maker, model, type)
- PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
- Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)

The question is to find the makers producing PCs but not laptops.

The query written by me is

```
select maker
from product, pc
where product.model=pc.model
and maker not in
(
  select maker
  from product,laptop
  where product.model=laptop.model
 )
```

And the message I am getting is

> Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.

- Wrong number of records (more by 11).

Comment: If you are learning SQL, why aren't you using `JOIN`?

Comment: Gordon's comment is an important one and shouldn't be dismissed by the learner. The syntax you have used is not ANSI standard and is generally deprecated.

Comment: I have tried using natural join but it is not accepting.Can you just write a correct query for it.

Comment: Use `select distinct maker` instead of `select maker`.

Comment: @forpas This is also not working again I am getting the message ---Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `join` with `not exists` :

```
select distinct p.maker
from product p inner join
     pc
     on pc.model = p.model 
where not exists (select 1 from laptop l where l.model = p.model);
```

However, `join` will produce duplicate rows if `pc` table has duplicate rows. So, you can use `exists` instead :

```
select p.maker
from product p
where exists (select 1 from pc where pc.model = p.model) and
      not exists (select 1 from laptop l where l.model = p.model);
```

Comment: This is not a right query.It is giving wrong dataset.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi . . . What's wrong data-set, you get ?

Comment: This query is giving (A,A,B,E) but the right answer is (E).

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi. . . Why `E` only ? Why not `A OR B` ? Can you please describe with your sample data in question.

Comment: I also don't know the sample data.I have provided the link of the question i.e.,http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref. .You can run your query to check the result.